# SQL compound index on multiple tables

Tags: sql, h2

I would like to have a small clarification of setting up a compound index across sql tables. Could someone please let me know if it is at least possible wth h2 database?

Example: I have 2 tables, categories and customer. Each category has lot of customers. So, the requirement is to allow one customer to buy only product in each category [or in other words, customer_id must be unique for each category]. However there are millions of records, so the following query (to check for uniqueness) is not much effective.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM CATEGORIES c 
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ct 
on c.CUSTOMER_ID=ct.id 
WHERE c.id = '1' AND ct.EMAIL='joe@xzy.com'
```

It takes few seconds for processing. So the question is, is it possible to create a index for both these tables like below ?

```
CREATE INDEX "TEST" ON "CATEGORY" ("CUSTOMER_ID") and "CUSTOMER" ON CUSTOMER("EMAIL)
```

categories

```
| id | categoryname    | CUSTOMER_ID |
+----+---------+---------+--------------
|  1 |  electronics      |      1      |
|  2 |  food             |      2      |
```

customer

```
| id | name  | city     | EMAIL
+----+------------------+-------
|  1 |  Joe  | Newyork   |  joe@xyz.com
|  2 |  Ross | Washington| ross@xzy.com
| .. |  .... | ..... |
```

Comment: index ct.email, ct.id in that order

Comment: As far as I know you can't create an index for multiple tables, but you could produce a  `View` and index the `View` like you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need no such thing as a "compound index across tables".  You just need an index on categories.CUSTOMER_ID, which will speed up all lookups of some particular CUSTOMER_ID in your categories table.

That said, your design has serious issues.  Your 'categories' table serves two distinct purposes : one, to say something about categories per se, two, to say which customers participate in which categories.  if you try to look at this through the glasses of normalization theory, or you try to identify *all* the "reasonable" keys for your tables, you will inevitably find that your categories table as it stands must be split into categories (id, name) and categories_customers_part (category_id, customer_id).

Then you can enforce your business rule by declaring the composite key (category_id, customer_id) on the latter, and you won't even need to do your query anymore.

Comment: Yeah you are right but we have this design in production env and changing the structure is lot of effort. I know it is really bad idea to make a query to check for uniqueness but i think am left with no choice :(